# How to fetch data from a PHP page that encodes JSON?

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Please help me guys. I've been figuring how to solve this problem for several hours already but I still don't know how. ><

This is my php page that displays value in JSON Format.

jsonfile.php :

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","online_evaluation_revised") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from tblaccount";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);


    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

it display something like this:

```
[{"account_id":"89","username":"2012100014","password":"25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad"},{"account_id":"90","username":"2012102400","password":"25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad"},{"account_id":"91","username":"2012101087","password":"25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad"},{"account_id":"92","username":"2011102090","password":"25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad"}]
```

however, I don't how to fetch/transfer these data to my services.js and controller.js.

Here is my services.js:

```
app.service("myService", function($http,$q)
{
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('resources/json/jsonfile.php').then(function(data)
  {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  this.getAccounts = function()
  {
    return deferred.promise;
  }

})
```

here is my controller.js:

```
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,myService)
{
  var promise = myService.getAccounts();
  promise.then(function (data)
  {
    $scope.allAccounts = data;
    var accounts = data;
    console.log($scope.allAccounts);
  });

})
```

Whenever I use the data using the format above, it gives me something like this in the console log:

```
Object {data: "<?php
↵    //open connection to mysql db
↵    $con…db connection
↵    mysqli_close($connection);
↵?>", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

Weird because if I use the format above when fetching a file in JSON format (not in PHP), it gives me array objects.

Answer (score 0):

For This To Access Data in Js File YOu Have to use ajax.
call ajax when ever you want data.

for More Details you refer below link.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$http.get('resources/json/jsonfile.php',{ responseType : 'json' })
```

Comment: Can you console.log your Ajax response? 

`$http.get('resources/json/jsonfile.php').then(function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
  });`